# $\mathbb E[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(X;\theta)]^2$ and $\mathbb E[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(X;\theta)]$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, estimation

$f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi[1+(x-\theta)^2]}$; $-\infty<x<\infty,\quad-\infty<\theta<\infty$

$\log f(x;\theta)=\log (\frac{1}{\pi[1+(x-\theta)^2]})$

$\Rightarrow \log f(x;\theta)=\log(1)-\log(\pi[1+(x-\theta)^2])$

$\Rightarrow \log f(x;\theta)=0-\log(\pi)-\log[1+(x-\theta)^2]$

$\Rightarrow \log f(x;\theta)=-\log(\pi)-\log[1+(x-\theta)^2]$

Now

$\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(x;\theta)$
$=0-\frac{1}{[1+(x-\theta)^2]}2(x-\theta)(-1)$
$=\frac{2(x-\theta)}{[1+(x-\theta)^2]}$

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(x;\theta)$

$=2\frac{[1+(x-\theta)^2]\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}(x-\theta)-(x-\theta)\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}[1+(x-\theta)^2]}{[1+(x-\theta)^2]^2}$

$=2\frac{[1+(x-\theta)^2](-1)-(x-\theta)2(x-\theta)(-1)}{[1+(x-\theta)^2]^2}$

$=2\frac{(x-\theta)^2-1}{[1+(x-\theta)^2]^2}$

I have tried to take the *Expectation* of $[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(x;\theta)]^2$ and $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(x;\theta)$ and simplify the resulting equations,but i couldn't.

$\mathbb E[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(X;\theta)]^2=\mathbb E[\frac{2(x-\theta)}{[1+(x-\theta)^2]}]^2$

$\mathbb E[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(X;\theta)]=\mathbb E[2\frac{(x-\theta)^2-1}{[1+(x-\theta)^2]^2}]$

please compute the

$\mathbb E[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\log f(X;\theta)]^2$ and $\mathbb E[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}\log f(X;\theta)]$

Comment: If it helps (and without giving the answer outright), the probability distribution function has a well-known name and is oft-analyzed, and the specific expectations you are trying to compute are also well-known and oft-analyzed.

Comment: if it is oft-analyzed, then it would be so kind if i get the well-known result without asking for computation.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2158292/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We wish to find the Expectation of The Function of The Cauchy Random Variable.

---

Let $f_X(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{\pi(1+(x-\theta)^2)}$, with $x\in(-\infty,+\infty)$ and $\theta\in(-\infty,+\infty)$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
log f_X(x;\theta) & = (-1)\log\pi(1+(x-\theta)^2) \\
& = (-1)[\log \pi + \log(1+(x-\theta)^2)] \\
& = -\log \pi - \log(1+(x-\theta)^2)
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \log f_X(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta} & = 0 + (-1)\frac{1}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(1+(x-\theta)^2) \\
& = (-1)\frac{1}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)}\cdot 2 (x-\theta)^1 \cdot (-1) \\
& = (+1)\cdot \frac{2(x-\theta)}{1+(x-\theta)^2} = \frac{2x-2\theta}{1+(x-\theta)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
where we have used the facts:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \log x & = \frac1x \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \log f(x) & = \frac{1}{u(x)} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} u(x)
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial^2 \log f_X(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta^2} & = \frac{(-2)(1+(x-\theta)^2) - 2(x-\theta)^1 (-1)(2x-2\theta)}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^2} \\
& = \frac{-2\cdot(1+(x-\theta)^2)+2(x-\theta)\cdot2(x-\theta)}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^2} \\
& = \frac{-2-2(x-\theta)^2 + 4(x-\theta)^2}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^2} \\
& = \frac{-2 + 2(x-\theta)^2}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^2} \\
& = \frac{2\cdot((x-\theta)^2 - 1)}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Let: $$
\begin{aligned}
A & = \left(\frac{\partial \log f_X(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta}\right)^2 = \frac{4(x-\theta)^2}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^2} \\
B & = \frac{\partial^2 \log f_X(x;\theta)}{\partial \theta^2} = \frac{2((x-\theta)^2 - 1)}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^2}
\end{aligned}
$$

As a hint, we will only be solving $E_X[A]$. The same mathematical principles can be used to solve $E_X[B]$.

---

$$
\begin{aligned}
E_X[A] & = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} A\cdot f_X(x;\theta)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{4\cdot(x-\theta)^2}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^2} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi(1+(x-\theta)^2)}\,\mathrm{d}x \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{4}{\pi}\cdot \frac{(x-\theta)^2}{(1+(x-\theta)^2)^3} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$
Using **u-substitution**, let $u = x-\theta$, $\mathrm{d}u = \mathrm{d}x$, $u_\mathrm{lower} = -\infty - \theta = -\infty$, $u_\mathrm{upper} = +\infty - \theta = +\infty$.
Then,
$$
E_X[A] = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{4}{\pi} \frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)^3} \, \mathrm{d}u
$$
Now, recall the **Trigonometric Identities**: $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$, $1 + \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x$, $\sec x = \frac{1}{\cos x}$. Furthermore, recall the following **Derivatives of Trigonometric Functions**: $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sin x = \cos x$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\cos x = -\sin x$, and $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\tan x = \sec^2 x$.

Applying the **Trigonometric Substitution Technique**, let $u = \tan \theta$, $\mathrm{d}u = \sec^2 \theta \mathrm{d}\theta$. This implies $\theta = \tan^{-1}u$. Then, $\theta_\textrm{lower} = \tan^{-1}(-\infty) = -\frac\pi 2$ and $\theta_\textrm{upper} = \tan^{-1}(+\infty) = +\frac\pi 2$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
E_X[A] & = \int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \frac{4}{\pi} \cdot \frac{\tan^2 \theta}{(1+\tan^2 \theta)^3} \sec^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
& = \int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \frac{4}{\pi} \cdot \frac{\tan^2 \theta (\sec^2 \theta)^1}{(\sec^2 \theta)^3} \, \mathrm{d} \theta \\
& = \int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \frac{4}{\pi}\cdot \frac{\tan^2 \theta}{(\sec^2 \theta)^2}\, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
& = \int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \frac{4}{\pi} \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
& = \int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \frac{4}{\pi} (1-\cos^2 \theta)\cos^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
& = \int_{-\frac \pi 2}^{+\frac \pi 2} \frac{4}{\pi}(\cos^2 \theta - \cos^4 \theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta
\end{aligned}
$$

Recall the following **Properties of Even Functions**: If $f(x)$ is even, then $\int_{-A}^{+A}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 2\int_{0}^{+A}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$. If $f(x)$ is even, then $[f(x)]^n$ is even.

Then, 
$$
E_X[A] = \frac{8}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2}(\cos^2 \theta - \cos^4 \theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta.
$$

---

Now, we take a slight diversion and calculate a **Useful Integral**.
$$
C(n) = \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2}\cos^n x \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} (\cos^1 x)(\cos^{n-1}x)\, \mathrm{d}x.
$$
Recall **Integration by Parts**: $\int_{a}^{b}u\, \mathrm{d}v = uv|_{a}^{b} - \int_{a}^{b}v\,\mathrm{du}$. Let $u = \cos^{n-1}x = (\cos x)^{n-1}$, $\mathrm{d}v = \cos x\, \mathrm{d}x$. Then, $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}u = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(\cos x)^{n-1} = (n-1)(\cos x)^{n-2}(-1)(\sin x)$, and $v = \sin x$. The calculations below hold for $n \neq 1$. (If $n = 1$, we have the expression $0^0$, which is undefined, so we should calculate the $n = 1$ case separately.)
$$
\begin{aligned}
C(n) & = \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} \underbrace{(\cos^{n-1} x)}_{u}\underbrace{(\cos^1 x)\, \mathrm{d}x}_{\mathrm{d}v} \\
& = \cos^{n-1}x \sin x |_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} - \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2}\sin x (n-1) (\cos x)^{n-2} (-1)\sin x \, \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \underbrace{\left(\cos \frac \pi 2\right)}_{0} \sin \frac \pi 2 - (\cos 0)^{n-1}\underbrace{\sin 0}_0 + \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2}(\sin^2 x) (n-1)(\cos x)^{n-2}\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} (\sin^2 x)(n-1)(\cos^{n-2}x)\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& = \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} (1-\cos^2 x)(n-1)(\cos^{n-2}x)\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& = (n-1)\int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} (1-\cos^2 x)\cos^{n-2}x\,\mathrm{d}x \\
& = (n-1) \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2}(\cos^{n-2}x - \cos^n x)\, \mathrm{d}x \\
& = (n-1)\left[\int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2}\cos^{n-2} x\, \mathrm{d}x - \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2}\cos^n x \, \mathrm{d}x\right] \\
& = (n-1)[C(n-2) - C(n)]
\end{aligned}
$$
Then,
$$
\begin{aligned}
C(n)+(n-1)C(n) = (n-1)C(n-2) & \Rightarrow C(n)(1 + (n-1)) = (n-1)\cdot C(n-2) \\
& \Rightarrow C(n) = \frac{(n-1)C(n-2)}{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
Plugging in the relevant values of $n$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
C(0) & = \int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} (1)\,\mathrm{d}x = + \frac \pi 2 \\
C(2) & = \frac12 \cdot C(0) = \frac12 \cdot \frac \pi 2 = +\frac \pi 4 \\
C(4) & = \frac34 \cdot C(2) = \frac34 \cdot \frac \pi 4 = \frac{3}{16}\pi.
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Returning to where we left off,
$$
\begin{aligned}
E_X[A] & = \frac{8}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} (\cos^2 \theta - \cos^4 \theta)\, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
& = \frac{8}{\pi}\left[\int_{0}^{+\frac \pi 2} \cos^2 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta - \int_{0}^{+\frac ]pi 2}]cos^4 \theta \, \mathrm{d}\theta\right] \\
& = \frac{8}{\pi}[C(2)-C(4)] \\
& = \frac{8}{\pi}\left[\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{3\pi}{16}\right] \\
& = \frac{8}{\pi}\left[\frac{4\pi}{16} - \frac{3\pi}{16}\right] = \frac{8}{\pi}\cdot \frac{\pi}{16} = \frac12.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. You are excellent.